# Phantom and line break

Tags: line-breaking

I want to make a cloze test using LaTeX. My Idea was to use the `\phantom` command to produce the space:

```
Some text \underline{\phantom{some text to complete}} some more text.
```

Now the problem is that `\phantom` seems to handle "some text to complete" as one word and does not break lines.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

Some text \underline{\phantom{some  text to complete some  text to complete
some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some    text
to complete some  text to complete}} some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless you are setting the document in a large size the space created by `\phantom` will be too small for manual completion. I'd suggest to take a look at the [exam](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) package.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. However exam seems to be a documentclass and I don't want to change the documentclass.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Neither `\underline` nor `\phantom` allow for line breaks because they use the so called *restricted horizontal mode*, i.e. the same as a `\mbox{...}`. Your application reminded me about the `censor` package which is able to remove text and replace it by black bars or underlines. However, it seems also not to support line breaks. The `ulem` package gives `\uline` which underlines text in a line-breakable way. You could use it and redefine the internal macro which sets the text to use a phantom box. Note that this does only allows for line breaks at normal spaces and not for hyphenation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\def\UL@putbox{\ifx\UL@start\@empty \else % not inner
  \vrule\@width\z@ \LA@penalty\@M
  {\UL@skip\wd\UL@box \UL@leaders \kern-\UL@skip}%
    \phantom{\box\UL@box}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text \uline{some text to complete some  text to complete
some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some    text
to complete some  text to complete} some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image: Result or output]

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Is it possible to adjust your solution such that \uline has an optional arguments where you can say that it should make n-times of the space as in your \uline version?

Comment: @user4011: After thinking about it I don't think so, because this would affect the line breaking again.

Comment: Sidebar: The `censor` package now supports linebreaks through its `\blackout` command.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Hi, MartinScharrer . Your solution is really power. But could you please explain the macro part a little? I saw no `uline` in your macro, why it will affect uline?

Comment: @user15964: It's simple: The `\uline` uses `\UL@putbox` internally. I just analyzed `\uline` to discover its internal behavior. This way I don't have to recreate the whole complex macro, but can rely on the existing one.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Is it possible to have your macro work in math environment as well? Currently it underlines formulas without hiding them. Thanks!

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes but macros`\\\` or `newline` does not work in hiddent text with `blackout` though auto line-feed and \par works.

Comment: @lyl I have been working on an improved version that would support the \\ linebreaking.  It employs my new `tokcycle` package to rework things.

Comment: @lyl `\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021/03/10]
\makeatletter
\newif\ifexpandarg
\def\@dump#1{\addcytoks[1]{\expandafter\censor\expandafter{#1}}\def#1{}}
\def\spacelap{.6ex}
\def\censpace{\rlap{\censorrule{\spacelap}} \llap{\censorrule{\spacelap}}}
\def\@append#1#2{\tc@defx#1{#1#2}}`

Comment: @lyl `\xtokcycleenvironment\xblackoutenv
  {\@append\censored@word{##1}}
  {\tctestifcon\ifexpandarg{\expandafter\processtoks\expandafter{\expanded{##1}}}%
    {\processtoks{##1}}\@dump\censored@word\expandargfalse}
  {\@dump\censored@word\tctestifx{~##1}{\@append\censored@word{##1}}%
    {\tctestifx{\expanded##1}{\expandargtrue}{\addcytoks{##1}}}}
  {\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks{\censpace}}
  {\def\censored@word{}}
  {\@dump\censored@word}`

Comment: @lyl `\xtokcycleenvironment\blackoutenv
  {\@append\censored@word{##1}}
  {\tctestifcon\ifexpandarg{\expandafter\processtoks\expandafter{\expanded{##1}}}%
    {\processtoks{##1}}\@dump\censored@word\expandargfalse}
  {\@dump\censored@word\tctestifx{~##1}{\@append\censored@word{##1}}%
    {\tctestifx{\expanded##1}{\expandargtrue}{\addcytoks{##1}}}}
  {\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\def\censored@word{}}
  {\@dump\censored@word}
\makeatother`

Comment: @lyl Usage: `This \xblackoutenv is a test is a test. Checking for line wrap again and
  again.  This is really an issue if there is\\ a problem.
This is a test is a test. \textit{Checking for line wrap again and
  again.}  This is really an issue\endxblackoutenv`.  Still not finalized, but working on it.

Comment: Many many thanks @Steven B. Segletes for this. Would you please step to `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601473/how-to-hide-text-content-with-line-break-by-blackout`

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes When is the newest version of the package available in CTAN? Or other way to get it?

Comment: @lyl It is not yet available.  But if you copy/paste what I put above in to a preamble, along with loading the existing `censor` package, you will have access to the two pseudo-environments, `\blackoutenv...\endblackoutenv` and `\xblackoutenv...\endxblackoutenv`.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes I tried, and get this fault message: `! LaTeX Error: File `tokcycle.sty' not found.` I use xelatex.

Comment: @lyl You are missing the `tokcycle` package.  If you can't get your system to install it, then you can download files from https://ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle.  Needed for compilation are `tokcycle.sty` and `tokcycle.tex`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126604/discussion-between-lyl-and-steven-b-segletes).

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem by using the `color` package to write the phantom lines in white:

```
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\white}[1]{{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}

Some text \underline{\white{some text to complete}} some more text.
```

Comment: My lecture notes (provided as PDF) appear to be done like this (with blanks to fill in) and you can see what's in the blanks just by selecting the white text. That's harmless, since the fully-filled in notes get released a week or so after the lecture, but if you gave students a test in PDF format they would be able to see the answers, which isn't ideal.