# How to replace specific words with an underscore equal in length to the original word replaced in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, substitution

My problem is identical to [Phantom and line break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16003/phantom-and-line-break), however, I am using ConTeXt.

I am creating a cloze test, e.g.:

```
Frogs have four ____ and two eyes.
```

The original text in the source appears like this:

```
Froms have four \cloze{legs} and two eyes.
```

How can I get any text appearing inside `\cloze` to be replaced with underscores of the same length? E.g. "elephant" is replaced with 8 underscores.

Comment: Do you want underscore or will an underline equal to the length of the word will do? Should it break across lines? If so, do you want underscores under spaces as well?

Comment: It should simply appear as a continuous rule, which does not break across line. Anything between the `\cloze` is treated as one part, spaces also are replaced with underscores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need `\cloze` to break across lines, then the solution is simple:

```
\defineframed[cloze][frame=off, bottomframe=on, empty=yes]
```