# How to let users type in clozes in PDF?

Tags: pdf, context

I am using the code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59522/how-to-replace-specific-words-with-an-underscore-equal-in-length-to-the-original) to replace some text with a cloze, or "fill-in-the-blank". Students will fill in their answer there. Is there any way to let users type in the missing word in the blank, in the PDF, and save it with their answers in the blanks? They'll have access to Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: Not sure about a context solution, but the `acrotex` package can probably do this. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acrotex (not part of TL so you'll have to install it yourself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ConTeXt widgets.  Originally these were described in the [Interaction manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/interaction.pdf) but the chapter has been deleted.  I guess Hans has something new in the making.  You can still read the [old source code](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/4ba731dd6ff370a42984b4df050906fd9a884bc8/doc/context/sources/general/manuals/interaction/interaction-widgets.tex), though, and there is a little bit in [the Garden](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Widgets).

```
\setupinteraction[state=start]

\definefield[cloze][line]

\starttext

Frogs have four \field[cloze] and two eyes.

\stoptext
```