# Control ulines for cloze text

Tags: ulem

@Martin Scharrer suggested me the following amazing solution to make cloze texts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16004/4011

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\def\UL@putbox{\ifx\UL@start\@empty \else % not inner
  \vrule\@width\z@ \LA@penalty\@M
  {\UL@skip\wd\UL@box \UL@leaders \kern-\UL@skip}%
    \phantom{\box\UL@box}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text \uline{some text to complete some  text to complete
some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some    text
to complete some  text to complete} some more text.

\end{document}
```

Now I have some follow up questions about this approach:

1. How can I adjust this such that I can choose all the "underline styles" offered by the ulem package `\dotuline`, `\dashuline`, `\uwave` and`\uuline`?
2. How can I adjust the vertical space between the phantom text and the underline?
3. Is it possible to get a normal working version of `\uline` at the same time? (Call it for example `\Uline`, `\Uuline` etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Just use them.
2. `\setlength{\ULdepth}{...}`
3. The following example adds the switch `\ifulphantom` that can be set to enable or disable the phantom version for the macros of package `ulem`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\UL@putbox@original{%
  \let\UL@putbox@original\UL@putbox
  \def\UL@putbox@phantom{%
    \ifx\UL@start\@empty
    \else % not inner
      \vrule\@width\z@
      \LA@penalty\@M
      {\UL@skip\wd\UL@box \UL@leaders \kern-\UL@skip}%
      \phantom{\box\UL@box}%
    \fi
  }%
  \newif\ifulphantom
  \renewcommand*{\UL@putbox}{%
    \ifulphantom
      \expandafter\UL@putbox@phantom
    \else
      \expandafter\UL@putbox@original
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\ulphantomtrue

\begingroup
  \setlength{\ULdepth}{0pt}

  Some text \uline{some text to complete some  text to complete
  some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some
  text to complete some  text to complete} some more text.

  \setlength{\ULdepth}{1ex}

  Some text \uline{some text to complete some  text to complete
  some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some
  text to complete some  text to complete} some more text.
\endgroup

Some text \uuline{some text to complete some  text to complete
some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some
text to complete some  text to complete} some more text.

Some text \uwave{some text to complete some  text to complete
some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some
text to complete some  text to complete} some more text.

\ulphantomfalse

\begingroup
  \setlength{\ULdepth}{0pt}

  Some text \uline{some text to complete some  text to complete
  some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some
  text to complete some  text to complete} some more text.

  \setlength{\ULdepth}{1ex}

  Some text \uline{some text to complete some  text to complete
  some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some
  text to complete some  text to complete} some more text.
\endgroup

Some text \uuline{some text to complete some  text to complete
some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some
text to complete some  text to complete} some more text.

Some text \uwave{some text to complete some  text to complete
some  text to complete some  text to complete some  text to complete some
text to complete some  text to complete} some more text.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @student Switch `\ifulphantom` added that enables/disables the phantom versions of the macros from package `ulem`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cloze) named “[cloze](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cloze)” that specializes in creating cloze texts. You have to use LuaLaTeX or LuaTeX.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[show]{cloze}

\begin{document}
Some text \cloze{some text to complete some text to complete some text
to complete some text to complete some text to complete some text to
complete some  text to complete} some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: Cloze show]

Change the global options to `\usepackage[hide]{cloze}` or use `\clozehide` to hide the cloze text.

[image: Cloze hide]

Comment: +1 but what does "cloze text" mean?

Comment: Should it be "cloze test"? In German Lückentext. A text with gaps. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloze_test

Comment: Thank you very much. In French we say «texte à trous».

Comment: @JosefFriedrich Your package is great, but is there an option to have a dotted line for the cloze text? It would look much better in fractions where both the nominator and the denominator are hidden.

Comment: @Georgios unfortunately there is no option for dotted lines. Maybe the command \clozenol{} (cloze no line) will help you in fractions ... or a different cloze line color.