# How can I hide (or blur) some code in a listing?

Tags: listings, matlab

I have a code listing to write in a report, but I'd like to blur or hide some code parts with a colored box (of same length as the hidden text), so that readers cannot see the hidden parts. (Another requirement is that readers should not be able to copy & paste the hidden text from the PDF.)

As an example, I would like `b=c;` in the listing below to be hidden by a black box (or blurred).

For that, I define a `\confidentiel` for hiding text in a black box.
It works fine on normal text ouside a listing block. However, it doesn't work inside an `mcode` listing block: instead of producing a black box, `\confidentiel{code to hide or blur}` gets printed *verbatim*.

I'm using the [`mcode` package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) to display Matlab code, but I suppose the `listings` package (rather than `mcode`) is to blame here, because `mcode` uses the `listings` package; the problem likely occurs no matter which `listings` language is used.

Any idea?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} %to be used with package below:
\usepackage[confidentiel]{optional}
\newlength\heightconf
\newlength\widthconf
\newcommand\confidentiel[1]{%
\opt{confidentiel}{%
 \settoheight{\heightconf}{#1}%
 \settowidth{\widthconf}{#1}%
 \tikz{\node[inner sep=0pt,rectangle,draw,anchor=base,text height=\heightconf,text width=\widthconf,fill=black]{};}%
}%
\opt{libre}{#1}}

% package to display matlab code:

\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}

%starting document 
\begin{document}

  \confidentiel{this text is hidden with black box}
  this text is not hidden

    \begin{lstlisting}
    for i=1:3 do 
        a=b;
        \confidentiel{b=c;}
        c=d
    end
     \end{lstlisting}
% the code above does not hide b=c; but
% prints literaly \confidentiel{b=c} but i don't want that !

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  You probably just need to use `\escapechar`, so if I had a compilable example I could test it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Here, all code is shown:

[image]

## Here, some code is hidden:

[image]

Here are some implementation details.

### Invoke the "ghosts" of Martin Scharrer and Donald Arseneau

The `\confidentiel` macro defined below is based on a modified version of [Martin Scharrer's `\UL@putbox`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16003/21891), which is itself a "phantom" version of a macro defined in Donald Arseneau's [`ulem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package.

Such a macro applies cleanly over multiple lines, both inside and outside listings, and will prevent your readers from copying & pasting the hidden parts, no matter which PDF viewer they use.

### Indulge yourself

Instead of escaping to LaTeX only to invoke your `\confidentiel` macro, the following approach defines delimiters that apply `\confidentiel` to what they delimit.

The backtick character, `` ` ``, is an adequate (opening and closing) delimiter here, because it's unlikely to occur in Matlab code (it's only valid in Matlab string literals and system commands, nowhere else).

The main benefits of this approach is that hiding/unveiling stuff, either *locally* or *globally*, is fast and easy.

- Hiding/unveiling stuff **locally** only requires adding/removing two backticks (`` `...` ``), as opposed to adding/removing `\confidentiel{...}` each time;
- Hiding/unveiling stuff **globally** can be done by at the flip of the `\ifconfid` switch (comment/uncomment the line `\confidtrue`).

### Use `matlab-prettifier`

I recommend using the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package instead of `mcode`... but, as the author of the former, I'm somewhat biased `:p` Have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document/158816#158816), and see if you like [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) enough to migrate from `mcode`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newif\ifconfid
\confidtrue                   % comment this line out to unveil all hidden text
\colorlet{confidcolor}{black} % change the colour of boxes here (e.g. "red")


% ----------- implementation details -----------
\makeatletter

% from Martin's Scharrer's answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16004/21891)
\def\confid@UL@putbox{%
  \ifx\UL@start\@empty%
  \else % not inner
    \vrule\@width\z@ \LA@penalty\@M
    {\UL@skip\wd\UL@box \UL@leaders \kern-\UL@skip}%
    \phantom{\box\UL@box}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand\confidentiel{}%

\ifconfid
\renewcommand\confidentiel[1][confidcolor]{%
 \bgroup%
 \let\UL@putbox\confid@UL@putbox%
 \markoverwith{\hbox to.01em{\hss\textcolor{#1}{|}\hss}}\ULon%
}
\fi

\lst@AddToHook{Init}{%
  \ifconfid%
    \lstset{moredelim=[is][\confidentiel]``,keepspaces}%
  \else
    \lstset{moredelim=**[is][]``}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
% ----------- end of implementation details -----------


\lstset{
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\mlttfamily,
}

\begin{document}
\confidentiel{%
    this text is hidden\\
    this text is hidden\\
    this text is hidden\\
}%
\xout{test that \textsf{ulem} works}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i=1:3
  a=b;
  % Guess what's next...
  `b=c;`
  c=d;
end
`% this text is hidden
% this text is hidden
% this text is hidden
`
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I compared both `matlab-prettifier` and `mcode`: with `mcode` the result is just... horrible! The code is not automatically line-breaked on the right and the font is not as beautiful as matlab-prettifier. Moreover if I tried some commands like `\confidentiel` with an escapechar inside a big `code.m` included with `\lstinputlisting{code.m}`, the boxes are gray, not black. Moreover, I got a strange bug (also with your package) with `\blackout` command of `censor` package (escapechar used : ç): using it twice inside an included code, that doesn't work : code after `\blackout{` doesn't display.

Comment: Félicitations Julien et merci pour ta fonction `\confidentiel` qui réalise à merveille ce que je souhaitais ! Finally, how could I add an option in the preamble to change the color of boxes hiding the code ? Something like `\confidentiel[red]{text to hide}` would produce a red rectangle. Useful to hide different kinds of text in a PDF (code, normal text, etc...) without being able to copy/paste it.

Comment: @jyloup Thanks but, to be fair to `mcode`, you can also use any font with it, and you can always "manually" set the `breaklines` key to have automatic line-breaking. I also tried using the `censor` package in my attempt at answering the question, but I didn't manage to get it to work in this particular case; the `ulem` package ended up being more convenient. Adding a colour option for `\confidentiel` should be easy; stay tuned.

Comment: You can now use `\confidentiel[red]{stuff}`.

Comment: Wow I tested it and the result is just great ! In fact, about `mcode`, the line-breaking is not set by default, but is set up automatically on matlab-prettifier and is more handy and more natural for PDF rendering. Thanks 1000 times! your solution closes this post.

Answer (score 6):

As suspected you simply need to add the `escapechar` so that `listings` knows that you want to execute this code:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `escapechar` can be any character that does not appear in the `listing`, and indicates the start and end of the code that is to be executed. In the MWE below I used the `$` charaacter.
- As [the `mcode` package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) is not part of the standard distribution, I used the `listings` package directly, but should work with [`mcode`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package)  as well.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} %to be used with package below:
\usepackage[confidentiel]{optional}
\newlength\heightconf
\newlength\widthconf
\newcommand\confidentiel[1]{%
\opt{confidentiel}{%
 \settoheight{\heightconf}{#1}%
 \settowidth{\widthconf}{#1}%
 \tikz{\node[inner sep=0pt,rectangle,draw,anchor=base,text height=\heightconf,text width=\widthconf,fill=black]{};}%
}%
\opt{libre}{#1}}

% package to display matlab code:

%\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage{listings}

%starting document 
\begin{document}

  \confidentiel{this text is hidden with black box}
  this text IS hidden outside of \verb|listings|

    \begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=$]
    for i=1:3 do 
        a=b;
        $\confidentiel{b=c;}$ And now, also hidden IN listings
        c=d
    end
     \end{lstlisting}
% the code above does not hide b=c; but
% prints literaly \confidentiel{b=c} but i don't want that !

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect I didnt know this command escapechar that's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot for all your helps.:-)

Comment: Nice trick to draw a rectangle of the same size as the hidden text to prevent copy. However, this approach doesn't work well if `\confidentiel`'s argument contains line breaks; try, for instance, `\confidentiel{this text is hidden\\ with black box}`

Comment: @Jubobs: The `\confidentiel` macro was provided in the question, so I did not do anything with that. I guess with the given definition of `\confidentiel`, one would have to use it on each line. There are ways to get it work across multiple lines, but I don't think that that is related to being in a `listings` environment.

Comment: @PeterGrill You're right. I hadn't noticed you used the same macro as given in the question and, in fact, the OP does not require the macro to be compatible with a multi-line argument in his question. I was referring to the OP's feedback in his (now deleted) answer.