# How can I hide (or blur) some code in a pythontex environment?

Tags: verbatim, code, pythontex

My question is directly related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194443/how-can-i-hide-or-blur-some-code-in-a-listing.).

Does there exists a solution for pythontex ? At least for the verbatim environment. More precisely, let us consider the following MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\newboolean{gap}
\setboolean{gap}{false}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}


\begin{pyverbatim} #or pyblock etc. 
\hide{x=1}
y=2
\end{pyverbatim}

\end{document}
```

I would like that `x=1` appears if and only if `gap` is `true`.