# Invisible blind text

Tags: spacing, blindtext

I basically want to add invisible blind text to my document. To print the rough layout and take some notes on what I want to write inside each of the missing paragraphs.

I tried:

```
\phantom{\blindtext}
```

This only reserves one (very long) line of text.

```
\vspace{10cm}
```

This does not behave like text. I could add a lot of small `\vspace` but maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: You could set the textcolor to white: `\textcolor{white}{\blindtext}`.

Comment: Oh man... sometimes the answer is too obvious. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: There is also the package `transparent` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the text color to white achieved what I was trying to do.

As leandriis wrote in a comment:

```
\textcolor{white}{\blindtext}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a minipage or a vbox inside the `\phantom`-macro to get the real size.

With the blindtext inside a minipage you may get problems at pagebreaks, but a `\vbox` should do the work.

Check this example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

%Wrong
\fbox{
\phantom{\blindtext}
}

%Problems on page breaks
\fbox{
\phantom{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\blindtext\end{minipage}}
}

% The solution?
\fbox{%
\phantom{\vbox{\blindtext}}%
}

\fbox{\phantom{\vbox{\blindtext}}}

\end{document}
```

The `\fbox`es are added to make the space visible. They are not part of the solution.

---

Based on the comment, I expect this is a MWE for the problem:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

pre1: \blindtext

pre2: \blindtext

% \phantom{\blindtext}% One long line
\phantom{\vbox{\blindtext}}%correct paragraph, but in one block.

after \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Maybe there is another solution, but I don't expect that it can be solved with `\phantom`. See also [Phantom and line break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16003/phantom-and-line-break/)

Comment: It seems like the behavior is still different from adding just text. If the vbox is 'big' it gets moved to a new column leaving additional white space that would not be there if I added just the blind text.

Comment: Yes, in my example are some additional spaces. Can you try `\fbox{\phantom{\vbox{\blindtext}}}` (in one line). I will modify my answer to remove this spaces.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was worded poorly. I have a two column layout. Once the column is full the text continues at the next column. When I put the blind text into the `vbox` the whole text gets moved to the new column. This creates additional empty space (not white spaces) in the previous column. Thank you for your help

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16003/phantom-and-line-break/