# How to hide text content with line break \\ by \blackout

Tags: macros, spacing, text-decorations, lipsum

I'd like to hide some text which contain line breaks by `\\`(or `\newline`) with the macro `\blackout` frome the package `censor`, and failed--the hidden part has no line breaks at all, please see the attached figure. But `\par` in hidden text will make `\blackout` work well.

My question is: how to make `\blackout` support text with `\\`(or `\newline`).

Another question: `\blackout{\lipsum[1]}` causes fault. Why?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor,lipsum,geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}\parindent=0pt\noindent\noindent
|some\\ text|\\
|\blackout{some\\ text}|%typeset has not line feed.
%\blackout{\lipsum[1]} %Wrong use, why?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained to the OP on another thread, I am working on `censor` improvements which would address the issue of line-breaks.  In fact, it addresses the issue of macros in general.  While premature, I include it as `\makeatother` code.

It uses `tokcycle` pseudo-environments to process the input.  Under the regime provided, macros are simply passed through and not subject to censoring.  However, if the macro is fully expandable, one can use `\expanded{<\macro>}` and censoring will be applied to the expanded content.

To the OP's question of lipsum, `\lipsum` is not expandable, and thus, it cannot be censored as an argument to `\blackoutenv` or `\xblackoutenv`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{censor,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021/03/10]
\makeatletter
\newif\ifexpandarg
\def\@dump#1{\addcytoks[1]{\expandafter\censor\expandafter{#1}}\def#1{}}
\def\spacelap{.6ex}
\def\censpace{\rlap{\censorrule{\spacelap}} \llap{\censorrule{\spacelap}}}
\def\@append#1#2{\tc@defx#1{#1#2}}
\xtokcycleenvironment\xblackoutenv
  {\@append\censored@word{##1}}
  {\tctestifcon\ifexpandarg{\expandafter\processtoks\expandafter{\expanded{##1}}}%
    {\processtoks{##1}}\@dump\censored@word\expandargfalse}
  {\@dump\censored@word\tctestifx{~##1}{\@append\censored@word{##1}}%
    {\tctestifx{\expanded##1}{\expandargtrue}{\addcytoks{##1}}}}
  {\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks{\censpace}}
  {\def\censored@word{}}
  {\@dump\censored@word}
\xtokcycleenvironment\blackoutenv
  {\@append\censored@word{##1}}
  {\tctestifcon\ifexpandarg{\expandafter\processtoks\expandafter{\expanded{##1}}}%
    {\processtoks{##1}}\@dump\censored@word\expandargfalse}
  {\@dump\censored@word\tctestifx{~##1}{\@append\censored@word{##1}}%
    {\tctestifx{\expanded##1}{\expandargtrue}{\addcytoks{##1}}}}
  {\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\def\censored@word{}}
  {\@dump\censored@word}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt\noindent\noindent
|some\\ text |\\
|\blackoutenv 
some\\text
\endblackoutenv|

\blackoutenv 
today is \today

today is \expanded{\today}
\endblackoutenv

\xblackoutenv 
today is \today

today is \expanded{\today}
\endxblackoutenv

but lipsum is not expandable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When is it available for `blackout` to support `\\\`?

Comment: @lyl I'm not sure when I will get around to fully verifying my changes, prior releasing a new package version.  But, if you prefer the `\blackout{...}` syntax to `\blackoutenv...\endblackoutenv`, then you could `\renewcommand\blackout[1]{\blackoutenv#1\endblackoutenv}`, using the code from above.

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes Many thanks for your proposal and I will be waiting for your new package version.